# Weird compilation error: catastrophic error: section length mismatch in array expression compilation aborted for shocktube.c

Tags: c++, arrays, icc

I am facing trouble in compiling a simple piece of code. Following are the details:

Variable declaration:

```
double q_old[3][N], q_new[3][N], u[3][N], flux[3][N+1], fl[3][N+1], fr[3][N+1];
```

The following line seems to be the source of error:

```
fl[0][1:N+1] = u[1][0:N]*u[0][0:N]; // this does not work
fl[0][1:N] = u[1][0:N]*u[0][0:N]; // this works
```

The error:

```
shocktube.c(47): catastrophic error: section length mismatch in array expression
compilation aborted for shocktube.c (code 1)
```

I am using intel icpc compiler. The **first** statement **does not** work but the second does, which is really weird because AFAIK the size of the LHS array in the first statement will be N(index varying from 1 to N) and size of RHS should also be N(0 to N-1), while in the second statement size of LHS is N-1.

Thanks,

Comment: This is about an intel-only extension. [C/C++ Extensions for Array Notations Programming Model](https://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/studio/composer/en-us/2011Update/compiler_c/optaps/common/optaps_par_cean_prog.htm)

Comment: The error message probably points to an internal compiler error ('catastrophic' should not be applied to a user error).  It is unlikely that there's much you can do except work around it, presumably by not using the `N+1` notation.  You should probably look at the support page for instructions on reporting a bug.  It is a good chance to practice creating an SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)).  That might not be very many more lines of code than you show above, minus unused variables, plus enough code to make a skeletal function.

Comment: In the light of the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24253290/15168) by [nneonneo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1204143/nneonneo), it seems more likely to be user error than compiler error, but the term 'catastrophic' is perhaps a little too enthusiastic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Intel array section notation is **`[start:length]`**, not `[start:end]`. Therefore, this line

```
fl[0][1:N+1] = u[1][0:N]*u[0][0:N]; // this does not work
```

is invalid because you are indexing past the end of the array (specifically, you are asking for indices `[1, N+2)` in the `fl` array, whose last dimension only has `N+1` elements).

The error probably should be a little gentler ("catastrophic" is not a term I'd apply to a user error), but this is ultimately not the compiler's fault.